# Visual Studio remote debugging in classical Windows GUI application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, remote-debugging

I migrated an WinForm application to Core 3.0
now I'm missing the settings for remote debugging.

In the old project in the debugtab of the main project you could select the remote PCs name and set up the output path and you are ready to go.

[image: Remote setting screenshot]

Is remote debugging not supported in core GUI projects or do i miss some settings in the csproj file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You [weren't ready to go](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-csharp?view=vs-2019) - you had to install the remote tools, configure them, configure VS's debugger itself, deploy the application. What `Use remote machine` did was connect to the correct remote server and tell the Remote Tools to start the application deployed to a specific folder. I suspect this hasn't made it to the new project template yet.

Comment: Remote debugging still works. You can start the application on the remote machine and attach to it

Comment: Thanks, attaching to a remote process work perfect for me!